# Finding a general integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> $$ \int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln(1+{t}^{a})}{1+t} \;\mathrm{d}t} $$

I have tried many tings but I am just not successful in any of them - Feynman, summation inside integral, Beta function equivalents, various substitution to get the limits back so that I can integrate an easy function etc.

Comment: What kind of restrictions do you have on $a$?

Comment: For $a=1$, the result is $\frac{1}{2}(\log 2)^2$, and for $a=2$ it is $-\pi^2/48+\frac{3}{4}(\log 2)^2$. For $a=3$ it contains polylogarithms. I guess the general expression will be horrible, if possible to obtain an expression for.

Comment: $a$ can be any real number.

Answer (score 4):

If $a\in\mathbb{N}$, factor $1+t^a$ then exploit:
$$ \int \frac{\log(1-\alpha t)}{1+t}\,dt = \log(1-\alpha t)\log\left(\frac{\alpha+\alpha t}{1+\alpha}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-\alpha t}{1+\alpha}\right). $$
The last line can be easily checked through differentiation.

Comment: For example, what would you do for $ a = 1 + \sqrt{2} $ ?

Comment: @KartikSharma: that is not a natural number, so my answer does not cover that case. Anyway, you may approximate such $a$ with a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ and apply the identity above after the substitution $t=u^q$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! And very sorry that I didn't see the domain of $a$. Your method is nice for natural numbers. Any other methods than approximation because I have seen problems like this(for $ a = 2 + \sqrt{3}$)?